# Dotnet : Dockerfile No such file or directory Blazor

Tags: .net, docker, build, blazor

I am working on a Blazor build for a web app. I am having some issues with my BuildWebCompiler

I have this docker file:

```
# BUILD
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "Web/App.Web/App.Web.csproj"
RUN dotnet publish "Web/App.Web/App.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /out

# RUNTIME
FROM nginx:alpine AS final
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /out/wwwroot /usr/local/app/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

When I run the docker compose -> compose up, i have this issue:

```
#11 21.73   WebCompiler installing updated versions of the compilers...
#11 21.81 /root/.nuget/packages/buildwebcompiler/1.12.405/build/BuildWebCompiler.targets(12,9): error : No such file or directory [/FDC-Web/FDCApp.Web/FDCApp.Web.csproj]
```

If I removed

```
<PackageReference Include="BuildWebCompiler" Version="1.12.405" />
```

Docker will work but CSS doesn't work.

Note: I am running this under Linux containers.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issue? I'm facing this same error and have no clue how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

BuildWebCompiler is Windows only. Use Excubo.WebCompiler using the instructions on https://github.com/excubo-ag/WebCompiler. It works on all platforms.